# How to keep checked items across pagination requests in Laravel 8?

Tags: pagination, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project, and I need to keep checkboxes values checked while pagination.
What I can do to keep it's values while pagination, and then take it's values and store it in my database?

Comment: Use Laravel's [session](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session)

Comment: Any details about how to use it??

Comment: The documentation I linked doesn't have enough details?